# The p-adic subspace Theorem

Tags: diophantine-approximation

Could someone explain how the subspace theorem could be used to transfer results from archimedian valuatons to nonarchimedian ones?

Comment: This question is too vague.

Comment: I was just looking for an e.g. of how to apply it